# QGIS - select or export point attributes by polygon feature

Tags: qgis, polygon, layers, point, select-by-location

I have two layers, one polygons of boundaries (similar to say local government areas) and a point layer of hospitals.  I want to select all of the hospitals within a particular area (ie a particular polygon attribute).  This could be to a new shapefile but the next step is I want to export a list.

I know how to export attribute features to CSV but how do I select only the points within one boundary area?

Answer (score 1):

If the both layers have the same projection, you can use `Join Attribute by location` from `Vector -> Data Management Tool -> Join Attributes by location`. Try to use "Take attributes of first located feature" as shown below:

[image]

- `Target vector layer` is the point layer (hospitals)
- `Join vector layer` is the polygon layer

Then save the out data as shapefile. You can them export the output shapefile as CSV by `Right-click the layer in the table of contents -> Save as -> Choose CSV` from the `Format` list.

Comment: Thanks - your first requirement "If the both layers have the same projection" just helped me figure out why I kept getting zero matches!