# Default values in shapefile - point sampling tool

Tags: qgis, raster, shapefile, default

Is there a way in QGIS to get values in my point shapefile from different layers via point sampling tool as "default values" ?

E.g.

When I add a point in the shapefile the altitude (raster) and county (polygons) are auto-completed and I do not have to run the point sampling tool after every session to complete these values.

Comment: What GIS software are you using?

Comment: If you're using QGIS, the answer to this question should help: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/244048/qgis-select-or-export-point-attributes-by-polygon-feature